# JavaFX setting root of scene causes root to change size

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-8, scene

I have found that when I set the root of a scene (as advised - instead of simply setting the scene), the root pane is resized and does not fit in the stage properly, even though I supply the same dimensions as the stage. Screenshots can be seen in the links below.

If I use the setScene function, it works as expected and the root pane is the correct size, but there is a flash of a white screen between scene changes.

Here are examples from my project:

```
// resizes root pane - too small for stage
public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
    if (event.getSource() instanceof Button) {
        Button sourceButton = (Button)event.getSource();
        Stage primaryStage = (Stage ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

        if (sourceButton.getId().equals("back-button")) {
            primaryStage.getScene().setRoot(view.getWelcomePane()); 
        }
    }
}

public Pane getWelcomePane() {
    return new BorderPane(bpWelcomeMain); // bpWelcomeMain is the border pane that contains the page components
}
```

Or:

```
// produces 'flashing' between scene transition (but root pane is correct size)
public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
    if (event.getSource() instanceof Button) {
        Button sourceButton = (Button)event.getSource();
        Stage primaryStage = (Stage ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

        if (sourceButton.getId().equals("back-button")) {
            primaryStage.setScene(view.getWelcomeScene()); 
        }
    }
}

public Pane getWelcomeSceme() {
    return new Scene(bpWelcomeMain, 1500, 750); // bpWelcomeMain is the border pane that contains the page components
}
```

I have tried sizeToScene() as well as other things mentioned on other posts, but I am yet to discover a solution. The function setRoot() seems to work on one of my pages but not the others, even though they are all the same dimensions and the code for switching between the root panes is the same. I don't understand why setRoot() works for one but doesn't work for the other pages. I also don't understand why setScene() produces the correctly sized root pane but setRoot() does not.

So, I would like to use the setRoot() function without the root pane resizing, or setScene() without the flash between scene transitions (it ruins the fluidity of the UI). Is there a way?

[This is the result of setScene() (although it looks good because of the flashing between scene changes I feel like an epilepsy warning may be needed haha)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCMZI.png)

[This is the result of setRoot()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFH8w.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What I do not understand(maybe misunderstand) is why you want to set the size if you want it to stay the same? Maybe some code would help for better understanding.

Comment: [Read the JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#setRoot-javafx.scene.Parent-) if something doesn't work as intended figure out how its supposed to work and use it as intended.